# Why is my JLabel grid not functioning properly?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, grid-layout, imageicon

I'm trying to make a JLabel grid that updates everytime a button is pressed. Each button(north, south, east, west) moves an image from one JLabel to another position on the grid. I've written and re-written the code over and over, but I still can't get it to update properly. Why does the ImageIcon apear sometimes and not others? Where is my logic flawed?

Also, I did look at a bunch of other questions and such about this problem, but none of them help me...

Any and all help would be greatly apreciated.

```
ImageIcon man;
ImageIcon grass;
public int xPosition=0;
public int yPosition=0;

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.east.name()){
            System.out.println("east!");
            if(yPosition<4){
                xPosition++;
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.west.name()){
            System.out.println("west!");
            if(yPosition>0){
                xPosition--;
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.north.name()){
            System.out.println("north!");
            if(xPosition>0){
                yPosition--;
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.south.name()){
            System.out.println("south!");
            if(xPosition<4){
                yPosition++;
            }
        }
        URL imageMan = getClass().getResource("man.png");
        man= new ImageIcon(imageMan);

        URL imageGrass = getClass().getResource("grass.jpg");
        grass= new ImageIcon(imageGrass);

        int row=0;            
        if(row==0){
            while(row<=5){
                if(yPosition == row){
                    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                        if(i==xPosition){
                            points[i][row].setIcon(man);
                        }
                        else{
                            points[i][row].setIcon(grass); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                        points[i][row].setIcon(grass);
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }
        }
        row=0;
        System.out.println("codinates: ("+xPosition+","+yPosition+")");
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what I want the outcome to be, with the man being able to move around the screen using the buttons.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of what you want to achieve

Comment: Sure thing! I just added it to my question. @Madhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem and was able to simplify the code significantly.

Here is the new updated code that works:

```
ImageIcon man;
ImageIcon grass;
public int xPosition=0;
public int yPosition=0;
public int oldX =0;
public int oldY = 0;

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        oldX = xPosition;
        oldY = yPosition;    
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.east.name()){
            System.out.println("east!");
            if(xPosition<4){
                xPosition++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("can't go east!");
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.west.name()){
            System.out.println("west!");
            if(xPosition>0){
                xPosition--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("can't go west!");
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.north.name()){
            System.out.println("north!");
            if(yPosition>0){
                yPosition--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("can't go north!");
            }
        }
        if(evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.south.name()){
            System.out.println("south!");
            if(yPosition<4){
                yPosition++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("can't go south!");
            }
        }
        URL imageMan = getClass().getResource("man.png");
        man= new ImageIcon(imageMan);

        URL imageGrass = getClass().getResource("grass.jpg");
        grass= new ImageIcon(imageGrass);

        points[oldX][oldY].setIcon(grass);
        points[xPosition][yPosition].setIcon(man);

        System.out.println("codinates: ("+xPosition+","+yPosition+")");
    }
}
```